# JavaScript framework or tool for creating reports

Tags: javascript, reporting

I need a way to create reports in JavaScript. It has to show the report in HTML form and capable of exporting to PDF and CSV.

I know the usual way would be to create an HTML and CSV template and to use something like wkhtmltopdf to create the PDF.

But I think it should exist something more professional/complete, what would you recommend?

I use only FOSS software. So it has to be free software.